# Visual Studio Setup Proxy Authentification not working

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install Visual Studio on Mac OS. As usual he asks me for my proxy credentials when executing the installer (since I am behind a corporative Proxy). When I enter them, he keeps asking me for them without giving me an error.

I tried to use cntlm to avoid that problem, did not work. Whenever I try to execute the installer it says, that i am not connected to the internet.

The file I am trying to execute is the VisualStudioInstaller.dmg. Installing Visual Studio behind the same proxy on Windows worked.

So what can I do? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Had the same challenge, updated the proxy settings at system level https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/enter-proxy-server-settings-mchlp2591/mac and restarted the server to fix.